# I don't get into a loop even though the ResultSet is full

Tags: java

I have a result set which is not empty. It contains 6 columns. But if I want to use the loop, nothing happens.

If I call the stored procedure in SQL Server Management Studio with the same parameters as in the Java code, I got a result:

[image]

A few minutes ago everything worked

```
// That doesn't work because I can't get into the loop
if (con != null) {
        String an_id = "bkoubik";
        String AS_Aufruf = "exec BfV_Web.sp_Anwender_Start\n@AnwenderID = ?";

        try {
            PreparedStatement STMT = con.prepareStatement(AS_Aufruf);
            
            STMT.setString(1, an_id);

            ResultSet rs = STMT.executeQuery();
            
            //THIS IF STATEMENT IS NOT ENTERING, SO WHY THEN THE WHILE LOOP 
              IS NOT WORKING ?
            if (!rs.next() ) {
                System.out.println("no data");
            } 
    
            ResultSetMetaData meta = rs.getMetaData();
            int intRS = meta.getColumnCount();

            //THE LOOP IS NOT ENTERING
            while (rs.next()) { 

              [...]
            }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you try adding a simple print statement before, inside and after the while loop?

Comment: Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Your code matters, too. And hint: dont use images. Rather: use print statements to print the relevant information as text, and put that into your question. As nicely formatted text.

Comment: `rs.next()` iterates through *rows*, not *columns*.  And you seem to be obscuring what else your code might be doing.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Please do not include images in your question when text would be as good or better.

Answer (score 1):

intRS is the *column count*, not the *row count*. Your rs is likely empty.

Answer (score 0):

The first call to `rs.next()` (before the loop) already consumes the one and only row, so the next call (in the `while`) will return false.